# Wrong input shape for lstm keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

I came across a tutorial where the autor use a LSTM network for a time series prediction like this :

```python
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

We agree that the LSTM in this act like a normal NN (and is useless ?) since the LSTM got only one time step without stateful = TRUE , Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you are correct. The input shape should be (window length, features n).

However, there has been some success in transforming the input to the way you describe above. Below is a whitepaper where they were able to beat many top performing algorithms by doing so, and they used convolutional 1D layers to handle the time series pattern through a separate input.

[LSTM Fully Convolutional Networks for Time
Series Classification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.05206.pdf)

Comment: But in this case, what's the interest of using the LSTM that way ? What's the purpose of the LSTM in this case. Thanks for the paper, I will read it asap.

Comment: That's a good question and one that I don't think even they fully understood. The paper highlights that transformation as the key to their success over other algorithms. It's something I have yet to internalize enough to give a worthy explanation to.